# HyperLink click problem

Tags: asp.net

```
<li>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hlLogin" runat="server" 
    CssClass='<%# Css4Item(Eval("Page.Request.Path")) %>' 
    Text="Prijava" NavigateUrl="~/Login.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>
</li>

protected string Css4Item(object url)
{
  return url.ToString().EndsWith(Page.Request.Path,
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "active" : string.Empty;
}
```

How can i execute `<%# Css4Item(Eval("Page.Request.Path")) %>` that i will get path to my  Css4Item method when i click on hyperLink. This code is not executed. when i click on link nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will execute only into a bindable container, 'cause you're using the [Data-Binding expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx.aspx).

For some reason if you try to use the ResponseWrite into an attribute of webcontrols (something in the form '<%= %>') doesn't work, I think you've to set the CssClass from code behind, in the page lifecycle (probably on Page_Load).